# Como colocar url dinamicamente para caixas de comentários do facebook, específico para cada página

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, node.js

Lí em uma resposta que em php podemos fazer assim:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-width="687" data-numposts="7" data-colorscheme="light"></div>

  <?php
  $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  ?>
```

No entanto, eu uso node.js e template engine jade, com template engine jade podemos colocar na "página mestra" um "block" e dentro do bloco o conteúdo que aparecerá em todas as demais páginas, como poderia fazer para ter dinamicamente cada url das respectivas páginas, em Javascript, sem precisar colocar uma caixa de comentários com seus respectivos url em cada página do site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após alguns dias tentando achar a solução o salvador da nossas almas, Jesus Cristo, me direcionou ( não é por tanto achar a solução e sim para aproveitar a oportunidade de louvá-lo).

Esses códigos estão completos, bastando você copiar e colar onde você queira que apareça a caixa de comentários, dinamicamente irá renderizar seu domínio e adicionar uma caixa de comentários ùnica em cada página do seu site. Pode estar alterando o tamanho, cor etc ...

```
  <div id="thecomments"></div>
  <script>
     var thisurl = document.URL;
     function changeCommentsUrl(newUrl){
     // O plugin de comentarios facebook está dentro de parse.innerHTML 
     // e aparece no navegador dentro da div com id "thecomments"
     //e o data-href precisa estar com a variável " newUrl "
     document.getElementById('thecomments').innerHTML='';
     parser=document.getElementById('thecomments');
     parser.innerHTML='<div class="fb-comments" data-href="'+newUrl+'" data-width="687" data-numposts="7" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
     FB.XFBML.parse(parser);
     }
     changeCommentsUrl(thisurl);
  </script>

  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar como variavel no `res.render()`. 
Dentro do seu likebox.jade, ficiaria algo como:

```
div(class="fb-comments" data-href="#{minhaurl}" data-width="687" data-numposts="7" data-colorscheme="light")
```

sendo que vc deve compilar como

```
    res.render('/rota', 'minhaurl: req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;'); 
// aqui a gente passa a minhaurl
```

Você pode encontrar documentação sobre os req. usados acima: [req.originalUrl](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl) e [req.protocol](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.protocol)

Espero que ajude :)

Comment: É só copiar e colar o res.render no app.js ? Agradeço por esse norte, vou tentar achar a solução via express, tinha me esquecido do express.

Comment: Então, o res.render tem a ver com sua rota né, tem que configurar as funções que vc quiser pra puxar oq vc quiser e etc, mas o esquema é passar a variavel 'minhaurl' q vai dar boa :D

Comment: Agradeço a disponibilidade em ajudar, amigo, mas já encontrei a solução via javascript tradicional mesmo. Funciona exatamente como queria.